# Using Set Theory with arrays in programming

Tags: programming-languages, set

I was wondering if there are functions in any programming languages that allow you to test set theory.  For example a library or series of decent algorithms that can perform Combinatorics on large sets.

I don't need basic push/pop I would like to know for what programming languages do libraries exist for functions like UNION CONCAT INTERSECTIONS and Compliments, and comparison of sub sets for 100k+ element sets.

I know this sounds like a math question... maybe not but I am more looking for a Programming language that is designed to handle large sets quickly, because I know my algorithms will be slow.

Comment: This sounds like a job for SQL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard Python [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) type provides these operations. No guarantees that the speed will be what you need, since you haven't stated your performance requirements.

Answer (score 0):

- LINQ
- Functional languages
- R

....

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), it has great support of sets! For example:

```
val set1 = Set(1,2,3,4)
val set2 = Set(3,4,5,6)
set1 & set2 //gives intersection
set1 intersect set2 //also possible to write
set1 | set2 //or set1 union set2 gives union
set1 &~ set2 //or set1 diff set2 gives difference
```

Also different implementations that good for particular issues, they are SortedSet, BitSet, HashSet and etc.